# Do emails auto-forwarded from one Gmail account to another stop if marked as spam?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention, email-forwarding

What happens to mail that I've set to auto-forward from one Gmail account to another when I mark a message as spam? Does that mark the forwarding account and block it from sending in the future?

I have two Gmail accounts (A and B). I only check A; B forwards all its messages to A. Also, Google knows that B is my second email, so while logged into A I am able to send emails as if they come from B. I didn't enable one-click switch between accounts yet.

Now, sometimes messages which I consider to be spam arrive at B and get forwarded to A.

When I check my email in A, what happens if I mark those messages that got forwarded from B as spam? I am afraid that Gmail will then think that B is unreliable and stop accepting any messages from B after that.

For now, I am always going to B and marking those messages as spam there. In A I just delete them without marking them as spam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar setup and never had problems marking messages as spam.

I am sure **`mark as spam`** doesn't work that way.
Google can keep a track that you have enabled auto forwarding, and any emails that you mark as spam will be registered against the original sender and not your email ID.
Mark as spam is a one step process and if you ever mark a mail that you specifically sent from `B` to `A` you will never see another email from `B`. So don't worry and keep marking mails as spam if you feel so.

Comment: Do you have any references for this?

Comment: I have the similar setup  and never faced such an issue. SO its more of common sense and conclusion